# Proof of convergence of series

Tags: sequences-and-series

How would you prove that the following series converges?
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{3+k \sin (k^2)}{5^k}$$.

using the comparison test and relating to the geometric series

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Use this inequality

$$\vert3+k\sin(k^2)\vert\le 3+k$$
and then prove by the ratio test that the series $\sum \frac{3+k}{5^k}$ is convergent and use comparison to conclude.

Comment: the ratio test is not allowed to be used in this question. Alternatively, the comparison test is asked to be used. Sorry for not making this clear

Answer (score 1):

As already suggested in another answer, you have that $|3 + k \sin k^2| \le 3 + k$.

Notice that it can be proven by induction that $3 + k \le 2^k, \ k \ge 3$: for $k = 3$ it is true that $6 < 8$ and the jump from $k$ to $k+1$ is obtained by $3 + (k+1) = (3+k) + 1 < 2^k + 1 < 2^k + 2^k = 2^{k+1}$.

We can say then that

$$\left| \sum \limits _{k=1} ^\infty \frac {3 + k \sin k^2} {5^k} \right| \le \left| \frac {3 + \sin 1} 5 \right| + \left| \frac {3 + 2 \sin 4} {25} \right| + \sum \limits _{k=3} ^\infty \frac {2^k} {5^k}$$

and the last series is obviously convergent being a geometric series of ratio $\frac 2 5$.